# How to Change If-else statement into Switch Case?

Tags: java, android, performance

How to change my if-else statement into Switch Case structure?

```
if (apiName.equals(APIUrlConstant.getIsRegistrationenabledUrl())) {
    IsRegistrationEnableModel isRegistrationEnableModel = gson.fromJson(responsedata, IsRegistrationEnableModel.class);
    listener.onTaskPostExecute(isRegistrationEnableModel, requestData, responsedata);
} else if (apiName.equals(APIUrlConstant.AboutUs)) {
    // do Something
}else if (apiName.equals(APIUrlConstant.AddContentRating)) {
    // do Something
}
```

apiName is a String type. How to do that?

Comment: try writing some code

Comment: by looking at the correct syntax and re-writing the code. The only way 'simpler' to say this, is by providing the actual code,

Answer (score 0):

In the JDK 7 release, you can use a String object in the expression of a switch statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Comment: , which would be constants. But as Hamed Momeni states. `APIUrlConstant.getIsRegistrationenabledUrl()` is not a String/constant.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't. [Switch case expressions must be constant expressions](https://www.google.com/search?q=switch%20case%20expressions%20must%20be%20constant%20expressions&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and `APIUrlConstant.getIsRegistrationenabledUrl()` is not a constant expression.

Comment: same error showing. "Constant Expression Required". Is there any possible way by which I can use it?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra not as far as I can tell. You're just gonna have to go with `if-else`.

Comment: @Hamed You are right As Switch Control Statement Doesn't Handle Variable Results. It is Already Told Which Cases may come in a particular Situation.

Comment: @HamedMomeni for (at least) a part, he can: APIUrlConstant.AboutUs is most likely a constant, not a variable.

Comment: @Stultuske I assume he needs all conditions checked. So a partial answer is not what he needs.

Comment: seeing as he can put the final if inside the default case, I would not see why this is just a 'partial' thing. a lot is possible if you write your code correct. saying the above can not be done using a switch is not a partial answer, it's an incorrect one

Comment: @Stultuske What if he had another non-constant expression added to this equation. He can no longer opt in for the `default`.

Comment: @HamedMomeni you mean to say you think it is impossible to put an if else if inside a default block? as I said earlier "seeing as he can put the final if inside the default case".... I never suggested he should go 'free for all' in the default case